# Query optimization for using both group by and order by

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I am working on mysql querying a table which keeps on increasing every minute. The query is also being used for pagination also having the limit clause. The table consist of user session being visited on store website. I have already added indexes for store_id, session_id
Following is the query.

```
SELECT *,
    GROUP_CONCAT(email) as email_id 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM clickstream 
    WHERE clickstream.store_id = '' 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
) as clck 
GROUP BY session_id 
ORDER BY server_now DESC 
LIMIT ".$offset.",".PER_PAGE_PRODUCT_COUNT
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried doing an EXPLAIN to see that MySQL is actually using your indexes?

Comment: There seems to be no purpose to the sub query. You could just select directly from the clickstream table in the outer where (possibly adding an order clause to the GROUP_CONCAT). The use of a sub query will prevent MySQL using indexes for the GROUP BY clause. Further is server_now unique for a session_id?

Answer (score 0):

Your index on `store_id` will help you in this query, you can't Speed the query up further by other indices. You just can remove the subquery:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    GROUP_CONCAT(email ORDER BY id) as email_id
FROM 
    clickstream 
WHERE 
    clickstream.store_id = '' 
GROUP BY 
    session_id 
ORDER BY 
    server_now DESC 
LIMIT 
    $offset,PER_PAGE_PRODUCT_COUNT
```